# ¿Como impedir que se introduzca un objeto repetido en un array?PHP

Tags: php, array, poo

Tengo el siguiente código en el que le añado a un alumno una materia, lo que no sé es como hacer para que sólo pueda añadir una materia una única vez, es decir, que cuando quiero introducir la materia en el array, si esta ya se encuentre en el, no me deje añadirla y si no se encuentra en el, pues que me deje añadirla

```
<?php 
class Materia{
    $nombre;
    public function __construct($id,$nombre){
        $this->id=$id;
        $this->nombre=$nombre;
    }
}
?>
<?php 
class Alumno{
 $nombre;
 $misMaterias=array();
 public fucntion __construct($nombre){
    $this->nomre=$nombre;
 } 
 public function getMaterias(){
    return $this->misMaterias;
 }
 public function addMateria(Materia $pMateria){
  $this->misMaterias[] = $pMateria;
 }
}     
?>
<?php
$mates=new Materia('M1','matematicas');
$nuevoAlumno= new Alumno('Chris');
$nuevoAlumno->addMateria($mates);
$nuevoAlumno->addMateria($mates);
var_dump($nuevoAlumno);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te comenta Antonio puede estar bien, pero yo personalmente utilizaría el método contains de PHP. Y para añadir en el array, usaría array_push.

```
public function addMateria(Materia $pMateria){
    if(!misMaterias.contains($pMateria)){
        array_push($this->misMaterias, $pMateria);
    }
}
```

Es más sencillo, más limpio y más claro de entender si alguien tiene que leer el código.

Comment: me gusta tu respuesta, si que la veo mas sencilla de entender, gracias, pero... porqué usarías mejor `array_push` que la otra forma?

Comment: Simplicidad básicamente. El código cuando más sencillo, mejor.

Answer (score 1):

En el método addMateria, puedes recorrer el array para ver si existe así:

```
public function addMateria(Materia $pMateria){
  foreach($this->misMaterias as $currentMateria){
    //Si existe la materia, no la añadimos al array y salimos
    if($currentMateria->getId() == $pMateria->getId()) return;

    $this->misMaterias[] = $pMateria;  
 }
```

También podrías usar el id de la materia como key del array

```
public function addMateria(Materia $pMateria){
  $this->misMaterias[$pMateria->getId()] = $pMateria;  
 }
```

Comment: ¿No seria mejor utilizar in_array () ?